# Save a list as a list in a Pandas dataframe column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, concatenation, list-comprehension

I am trying to concatenate 2 (string)columns 'col1' and 'col2' in a dataframe, tokenize the concatenated string and save the resulting list as another new column 'result'.

Desired output:

```
col1              col2          result
apples bananas    oranges       ['apples','bananas','oranges']
mangoes           apples        ['mangoes','apples']
```

I am doing this:

```
df['result'] = df['col1'].str.cat(df['col2'],sep=" ")
df['result'] = df.result.apply(lambda result: list(re.split(r'\W+', result)))
```

But I get this as output:

```
col1              col2          result
apples bananas    oranges       [apples,bananas,oranges]
mangoes           apples        [mangoes,apples]
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution is fine, also is possible use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) if both columns are filled by strings.

`''` are not displayed only.

```
print (df[['col1','col2']].iloc[0].apply(type))
col1     <class 'str'>
col2     <class 'str'>
Name: 0, dtype: object

df['result'] = df['col1'].str.cat(df['col2'],sep=" ").str.split()
print (df)
             col1     col2                      result
0  apples bananas  oranges  [apples, bananas, oranges]
1         mangoes   apples           [mangoes, apples]
```

If first column is filled by lists and second by strings:

```
print (df[['col1','col2']].iloc[0].apply(type))
col1    <class 'list'>
col2     <class 'str'>
Name: 0, dtype: object

df['result'] = df['col1'] + df['col2'].str.split()
```

Comment: Could not use str after cat() function

Comment: @PythonNewbie - Can you try `df['result'] = df['col1'] + df['col2']` or `df['result'] = df['col1'] + df['col2'].str.split()` ?

Comment: Didn't work :( I think it's because of the data in col1 and col2

Comment: @PythonNewbie - What is `print (df[['col1','col2']].iloc[0].apply(type))` ?

Comment: <class 'str'> <class 'str'>

Comment: @PythonNewbie - What is error `df['result'] = df['col1'].str.cat(df['col2'],sep=" ").str.split()` ? Why cannot use `str.split` or your solution?

Comment: @PythonNewbie - Or you need `df['result'] = df['col1'].str.cat(df['col2'],sep=" ").str.findall('([a-zA-Z]\w+)'` ?

Answer (score 0):

This works :

Yo can relate your dataframe object by following code:

```
import pandas as pd

list1= ['Apple Banana','Mangos']
list2= ['Orange','Apples']

dataframe=pd.DataFrame(data=[list1,list2],columns=['Col1','Col2'])

concat_result= list(dataframe['Col1'] +" " + dataframe['Col2']) # concatenate both the columns and convert that into a list type and store it in concat_result label

new_List=[]  #Create new label type list so we can append values.
final_list=[] #Final object which will contain single quoted String.

for item in concat_result:   #Loop through the list and append the elements after splitting default space. 
    new_List.append(item.split())


for new in new_List:   #new_List has two child list, so iterate over them
    for_single_quote=[]
    for inner_list_string in new:  # child List elements
        for_single_quote.append("'%s'" %inner_list_string)
    final_list.append(for_single_quote)

dataframe['result']= final_list
```

Then finally add new row in dataframe and assign the list :

```
dataframe['result']= final_list
```

You will get your expected output.